# Valor de pico de um histograma

Tags: python, opencv, histograma

Meu código lê uma imagem e faz a transformação do modelo de cores RGB para HSV, e depois faço um histograma de frequência de cada canal (H, S e V), sendo que H varia de 0-179 e os demais de 0-255. Com plotagem do histograma é possível verificar picos nos canais H, S e V. Esse histograma mostra através do eixo vertical a quantidade de pixels e do eixo horizontal os canais H ,S e V. Estou querendo retornar os valores de H, S e V em que a quantidade de pixels é maior, ou seja, o pico do histograma de cada canal.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] Como fazer isso? Já utilizei o método np.amax() mas ele me retorna os valores máximos de cada canal (H = 179, S = 255 e V =255).

```
def show_hsv_hist(image):
    # Hue
    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 3))
    histr0 = cv2.calcHist([hsv], [0], None, [180], [0, 180])
    plt.plot(histr0)
    plt.xlim([0, 180])
    plt.title('Hue')

    # Saturation
    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 3))
    histr1 = cv2.calcHist([hsv], [1], None, [255], [0, 255])
    plt.xlim([0, 255])
    plt.plot(histr1)
    plt.title('Saturation')

    # Value
    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 3))
    histr2 = cv2.calcHist([hsv], [2], None, [255], [0, 255])
    plt.xlim([0,255])
    plt.plot(histr2)
    plt.title('Value')

    max_v = np.amax(v)
    print (max_v)
```

A moda pode descobrir o valor mais frequente para cada canal. Tem algum método para isso? Sei que existe no numpy mediana, média.

Comment: A moda pode descobrir o valor mais frequente para cada canal. Tem algum método para isso? Sei que existe no numpy mediana, média.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O valor de Y máximo e X máximo podem ser encontrados com a função [max()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) e [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
ymax = max(histr)
xmax, _ = np.where(histr == ymax)

print(xmax, ymax)
```

#### Código

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import urllib.request
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def show_hsv_hist(hsv):
    HSV = [['Hue', 0, 180], ['Saturation', 1, 255], ['Value', 2, 255]]
    for nome, canal, valor in HSV:
        # Gráfico
        plt.figure(figsize=(20, 3))
        hist = cv2.calcHist([hsv], [canal], None, [valor], [0, valor])
        plt.plot(hist)
        plt.xlim([0, valor])
        plt.title(nome)
        #Máximo
        ymax = max(hist)
        xmax, _ = np.where(hist == ymax)
        print(ymax, xmax)

resp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/32/Carrots_of_many_colors.jpg")
img = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
img = cv2.imdecode(img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

cv2.imshow('Original', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

show_hsv_hist(hsv)
plt.show()
```